# Stochastic Processes Book Recommendations

Tags: stochastic-processes, book-recommendation

I'm studying electronic communications engineering, specifically, signal processing, and I always find difficulty when studying stochastic processes subject.

Could you recommend me a student-friendly stochastic processes book that covers fundamentals of stochastic processes for electronic engineering studies?

I've approximately one semester to study for this then I'll take Stochastic Signal Processing lecture which is built on this fundamentals and continue with estimation theory.

I have Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes, Papoulis 3rd edition book but I didn't find it very helpful. Is newer versions are better?
 I'll do a self-study so I'm looking for the book which explains topics clearly. Also, if you have, related video lecture recommendations may be very helpful.

This lecture is very fundamental for my studies so I want to grab a well understanding on this subject.

Thanks

Comment: oskendal you can try that with Sarto

Comment: @GuyFsone I can only recall the SDE book by Oskendal. However, stochastic process for EE student seldom involves SDE, so maybe that book is not a good choice.

Comment: Maybe Parzen - Stochastic Processes?